# Get the value of a css attribute in a specific unit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code showing a red square with a "left" css attribute in percentage, i want to display the current value of that attribute using an alert in js, which is done, the problem is it is currently displayed in px.

```js
    var element = document.getElementById('square'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    left = style.getPropertyValue('left');

    alert(left);
```

```css
    #square{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        left: 10%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
 

<div id="square"></div>
```

The question is : How can i display it in percentage ? and if is that possible a similar method in jQuery to use less code.

Comment: I'm afraid you've to read the original value directly from the [CSSStyleSheet Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like the following:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('square'),
    left = element.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    alert((left / windowWidth) * 100)
```

```css
#square{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        left: 10%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
 

<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: Nice! You got it before me. It is kind of creepy how close your code was to mine. Had the exact variable names and such lol.

Comment: This works only if inspected element is directly in the `<body>` tag. Without surrounding divs.

Comment: You should check parent element width and also keep in mind, it still won't work for absolute elements.

Comment: No it's not ;) Please check: https://jsfiddle.net/cetxj1fn/ I know, it's ugly but as a result You will see two different numbers.