# Retrieve a elements CSS properties from element after looping the class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have looped every class called "move" and want to console their "left" values.
However I want to receive the unit in vmin because I have written their predefined values in css,in vmin. But when doing .style.left, I receive blank null value. When I use getComputedStyle it works but gives in pixel. please help.

```js
const firstTimeFunctionPolis = async (id) => {

        let move = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
        for(var i = 0; i < move.length; i++){
        console.log(move[i].style.left); //gives blank.
        
       }
        
    }
```

Comment: can you post more code

Comment: Very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52559578/get-the-value-of-a-css-attribute-in-a-specific-unit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the value of a css attribute in a specific unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52559578/get-the-value-of-a-css-attribute-in-a-specific-unit)

Comment: Although you haven't shown us how you've set the left value I assume that is in a stylesheet - which is why .style.left gives nothing as you haven't set the style.left (inline) property.

Comment: here is one of the element with the class {width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url(../assets/spike.png);
  top: 80%;
  transition-property: top, transform, left;
  transition-duration: 0.2s, 0.4s, 0.28s;
  left: 95%;}

Answer (score 0):

Using JS you can calculate (roughly) the equivalent vmin to a px value.

I say roughly because there are edge effects/rounding errors.

If you know that the vmin value is an integer you can round the result to get the correct value.

Try this on various viewport sizes:

```js
function leftValue() {
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const vw = window.innerWidth;
const vh = window.innerHeight;
const divLeft = window.getComputedStyle(div).left;
const vmin = Math.min(vw, vh);
console.log('left = ', divLeft, ((divLeft.replace('px','') * 100)/vmin) + 'vmin');
}
window.onload = leftValue;
window.onresize = leftValue;
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  left: 10vmin;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: doesnt work, the vmin value returned is way off

Comment: Hi, it works for me - the vmin value being between 9.9....and 10.1,,,,,, What system are you using? I've tested on Chrome/Edge on Windows 10. What values do you see?